# What is the docker command to view name of the current container?

Tags: docker

Is there a docker command to view name of the current container I am logged into.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995351/docker-how-to-get-container-information-from-within-the-container?

Comment: Do you really need the name or the container ID would suffice for your use case?